Is it normal that airdrop is so difficult to use?
I have a wallet that I use for my testing. I'm an experienced dev, but basically just starting in Solana. I'm trying programs and new features and need to get going on the projects but of course need to load SOL through airdrop. Somehow I've been able to get 2 SOL on each of both devnet and testnet.
I understand that the limit is something like 24 SOL per day and max of 2 SOL each attempt with somewhere around 5 seconds between
My question is not "what are the conditions for aquiring airdrops?" I know them..
But these conditions are very idealized. I understand that it gets congested and airdrops fail for timeouts, but it also seems that a failed attempt adds to the number of intents causing it to indicate that you have to wait 24 hours. When I wait for 24 hours, it's 24 hours that my work is halted!
Is there anyone who is a serious developer who needs these airdrops to be able to do test runs without interruption that has any suggestions to mitigate this problem? I did see the

airdropIfRequired from the @solana-developers/helpers

could be a possibility, but I'd prefer not to put code in my projects that won't be used on mainnet.
Perhaps creating a wallet on the side with like 50 SOL and transfer when needed...?
Any other sulutions that you all use to resolve this problem?
